# Jquery Show and Hide doesnt work? Something is missing and i can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(".social").hover(function() {
        $("h1", this).hide();
        $(".networks", this).fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $(".networks", this).hide();
        $("h1", this).fadeIn();
    });
</script>

<style>
.networks {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="social">
    <h1>Share this</h1>
    <div class="networks">
        <p>Twitter</p>
        <p>Facebook</p>
    </div>
</div>      

</body>
</html>
```

when i try it in http://jsfiddle.net/ppksR/, it's really working but when i copy paste it in my dreamweaver, its not working. What did i miss??? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

jsfiddle is wrapping the JavaScript code in `onLoad`, which you should do.  Wrap the script contents in:

```
$(function () {
    // your code
});
```

To have jsfiddle emulate what you are doing, change the `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basic jQuery 101.... the elements don't exist when your code is firing.

Wrap code in `document.ready`, or place code after the elements it refers to

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Also worth reading [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) in docs for better explanation.

**Edit** The reson code works in jsfiddle is due to dropdown in top left that says `onLoad`. fiddle automatically wraps code in a load handler when that is selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it:

```
 $( function(){ .....

 } );
```

This will make sure the code doesn't execute until the browser has read all of your HTML. Currently you are executing the code before any elements with `.social` are defined.

Comment: hi @Chacha102, i have the same problem. i tried wrapping it and it goes like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function(){
  $(".social").hover(function() {
  $("h1", this).hide();
  $(".networks", this).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
  $(".networks", this).hide();
  $("h1", this).fadeIn();
  });
  });

 </script>

But still no effect...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that code with another editor / browser locally? Maybe DW is not loading jQuery properly. Have you pasted the code to a plain text file and tested the page in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

That is just idle scripting.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $(".social").hover(function() {
    $("h1", this).hide();
    $(".networks", this).fadeIn();
    }, function() {
    $(".networks", this).hide();
    $("h1", this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

This line `$(document).ready(function(e) {` makes it start onLoad through the scripting.

This is what your the code does. http://jsfiddle.net/3SKqQ/